# jquery button gets multiple for each clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#content_2").append(
    $('<input>')
    .attr('type', 'submit')
    .attr('id', "btnDivisionSave")
    .val("Save")
);
$("#content_2").append(
    $('<input>')

    .attr('type', 'button')
    .attr('id', "btnRules")
    .val("Rules")
);
```

This is button creation using jquery.Now my problem is, if i click anywhere in the page, this jquery button gets multiple.(ie.button will appear multiple times the page for each click event)
Please anyone give idea. Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Add Complete code, when is the code executed? on which event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#content_2").find('input[type="submit"]').empty();  
$("#content_2").append(
    $('<input>')
    .attr('type', 'submit')
    .attr('id', "btnDivisionSave")
    .val("Save")
);
$("#content_2").append(
    $('<input>')

    .attr('type', 'button')
    .attr('id', "btnRules")
    .val("Rules")
);
```